# Транскрипция русских слов

Tags: фонетика

Как правильно  транскрибировать слово *здравствуйте*? [здраствуйт’э]?

Answer (score 1):

[здра́ствуй'т'э]

Фонетический разбор «здравствуйте»:

[источник 1](https://how-to-all.com/%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0:%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5)

[источник 2](http://znanija.com/task/6477761)

---

В предложенном Вами варианте неверно указан звук **й**:

й   [й'] - согласный, мягкий непарный, звонкий непарный, сонорный.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы уже изучали редуцированные гласные, то транскрипция будет такой: [з д р а с т в у й' т' ь]. Если же нет, то [з д р а с т в у й' т' э].

P. S. Не забудьте поставить ударение.

Answer (score 0):

[здраствуй'т'ь] В пятом классе нас учили использовать ер (ъ) и ерь (ь) на месте безударных гласных, только если они не стоят в первом предударном слоге. Хотя я не знаю, как учат в других местах. Возможно, более подходящая транскрипция выглядит так: [здраствуй'т'э] Конечно, не стоит забывать и про ударение. Надеюсь, что мой короткий и не очень подробный ответ является полезным.